# Failed to convert the ipynb to PDF

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

Today when I tried to convert my ipynb file to PDF, an error occured as follows:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
? 
! Emergency stop.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ?.
```

I had tried the simplest ipynb file without latex, but it still had the same error

By the way, **I have pandoc and tex live 2019 in my PATH**

It seems that it was because of the latex, but I have no idea

Thanks for solving my problem !

Comment: Can you please share the .ipynb file here? We really need this information to help you out. Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please do  go through https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: A ipynb file without anything will get this error

Comment: Even an empty file should be convertible to PDF. I have checked it myself.

Comment: Try converting to html instead.

Answer (score 3):

Export the ipynb file to HTML file. Then export HTML (on your server) to PDF. This way retains all the numerical and image outputs in your ipynb file